# mongodb, java & connections not getting closed

Tags: java, mongodb, connection

since some time I am experiencing a weird problem:

I have a spring 3 webapp with a Mongo() singelton instanciated by the spring IoC container. 
The Mongo class is getting @Autowired correctly and I can issues queries, updates and so on.

After some time, I experience exceptions on DBPortPool concerning timeout issuing a connection.

To trouble-shoot, I wrote a job dumping the pool statistics to the log files.

After some hours, I get this output:

```
Total  : 38
Used   : 8
Unused : 30
Detailed Usage: 
        Duration: 0, Namespace: null, No Documents 0, ThreadName: null, Class: class com.mongodb.InUseConnectionBean, OpCode: null, Query: null
Detailed Usage: 
        Duration: 0, Namespace: null, No Documents 0, ThreadName: null, Class: class com.mongodb.InUseConnectionBean, OpCode: null, Query: null
Detailed Usage: 
        Duration: 0, Namespace: null, No Documents 0, ThreadName: null, Class: class com.mongodb.InUseConnectionBean, OpCode: null, Query: null
Detailed Usage: 
        Duration: 0, Namespace: null, No Documents 0, ThreadName: null, Class: class com.mongodb.InUseConnectionBean, OpCode: null, Query: null
Detailed Usage: 
        Duration: 0, Namespace: null, No Documents 0, ThreadName: null, Class: class com.mongodb.InUseConnectionBean, OpCode: null, Query: null
Detailed Usage: 
        Duration: 0, Namespace: null, No Documents 0, ThreadName: null, Class: class com.mongodb.InUseConnectionBean, OpCode: null, Query: null
Detailed Usage: 
        Duration: 0, Namespace: null, No Documents 0, ThreadName: null, Class: class com.mongodb.InUseConnectionBean, OpCode: null, Query: null
Detailed Usage: 
        Duration: 0, Namespace: null, No Documents 0, ThreadName: null, Class: class com.mongodb.InUseConnectionBean, OpCode: null, Query: null
```

Basically, I simply print all properties of the class ConnectionPoolStatisticsBean.

Now, whats confusing: Normally, those variables Duration, Namespace, ThreadName, Class and Query are being filled with data. Not, these connections seem not to be getting released.

Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce this bug as of now.

Any hints how I can find out where these connections are stuck?

Thank you all for your help!

Jan

//Edit:

I do use:

DBCollection col = mongo.getDB(this.db).getCollection("collection");
col.insert(...)

I don't issue a db.requestStart(); or db.requestDone().

Comment: Please, provide us with your code.